# Aggregate and Proxy Eclipse Plugins

Tags: eclipse, plugins, nexus, mirror

For my organization, I'm trying to create a localized Eclipse update server that includes all of the plugins and configurations that my team typically needs.  This will reduce the load on our limited external bandwidth being used to pull down plugin updates.  A centralized mirror will allow the plugin to be retrieved once and then distributed to my team of developers.

This strategy is similar to how we use Sonatype's Nexus to mirror and proxy Maven artifacts & repositories for our team locally.  I've noticed that Nexus professional product does provide this sort of Eclipse plugin proxy and aggregation, but for a fee of $900/year, that's a bit too steep of a cost just to solve our external bandwidth problem.

I'm hoping there is an open source alternative to these features in nexus pro that has already been discovered.  Standing up and running my own update site is easy, but tracking down proper versions of each of our plugins is what i'd love to have help with.

**Steps in the right direction?**

I've found references to using the Eclipse Update Manager itself to accomplish this (described in this blog post http://www.denoo.info/2009/09/mirroring-eclipse-update-sites/), however that post is quite outdated and I'm unsure if it is still valid given Eclipse's changes to updates over the past 2 years.  EPMT is also mentioned (http://www.developerfusion.com/project/25052/epmt/) but that project seems to have been dormant for years.  If anyone has opinions on these methods, i'd be interested in them as well.

Thanks in advance.